# Magento2 How to get category custom image attribute on frontend phtml page

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I need to get category custom image attribute on frontend.

Anyone have solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: have you try any code and do you face any error?

Comment: U See my Updated Answer or Comment.......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try my way I get Category custom attribute image name `homepage_image`

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$catId = 328; /* Category ID */
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');

$categories = $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSelect('homepage_category')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $catId));
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
        <?php $homeimg = $category->getHomepageImage();
        if ($homeimg) : ?>
            <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="homepage-category-img">
                        <div class="category-image-extra">
                            <img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl. 'catalog/category/'$homeimg; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" width="420" />
                            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">category</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @Bhurio I am getting only image name. How to get catalog base url?

Comment: See my code i added href for category url..

Comment: I get url like this--------$mediaUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
<img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'catalog/category/'.$homeimg; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>">

Comment: Please update your comment

Comment: I update my code please check.......

Answer (score 0):

You can try using object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$catCustomAttImg = $category->getData('cat_custom_att_img');

if (!empty($catCustomAttImg)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $catCustomAttImg . '" />';
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to get attribute :-

```
$category_id = 20;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id);  
print($_category->getData('custom_attribute'));
```

After this, use media class to show image.

Comment: have you tried??

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: I had updated my answer please try once.